# is there a way to generate "incremental" patch set in gerrit using git?

Tags: git, gerrit

Firstly, I have one patchset1 for commitA, then I push the patchset to gerrit for review.
Then, I made some additional new changes by amending commitA, how could I separate these new changes from previous pushed patchset and generate a new patch set only for them without do a new commit?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do exactly, but I can think of 2 possibilities:

1. Fix some things in commitA.  That is typically why you amend a commit.  If that is the case, you are doing everything correctly.  You will end up with patchset 2 for commitA.
2. Create a new commit which has changes to go on top of commitA.  If that is the case, you shouldn't be amending commitA.  You should create a new commit and push it to Gerrit (don't use --amend when committing).  This will create patchset1 for commitB in Gerrit.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the "Change-Id" in the commit message through "git commit --amend" and then do the push. A new Id will be assigned to the commit automatically and that will create a new gerrit patch set. You can see that a new Id has been assigned via "git log" after doing the "amend".